# positioning div elements inside each other

Tags: html, css

There is a weird downward shift of the div's on both sides of the page. Definitely something to do with relative and absolute positioning. I've heard a lot about setting the elements width and height when working with position:absolute and relative but no luck.

Is there a better way of positioning these containers inside each other also, all padding and margin is 0px (stated in body tag).

What it's supposed to look like: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrExb.jpg

What I have made so far: !https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dei5.jpg

**CSS:**

```
#mid-section-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.apps-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 617px;
    background-color: black;
}
#monthly-leaderboard {
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
#tournament-board {
    width: 800px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
.boards-container-nav {
    background-color: #363636;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #25b6e6;
}
#monthly-leaderboard-header {
    height: 85px;
}
#tournament-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
}
.apps-content-container {
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#monthly-content {
    width: 286px;
}
#tourn-content {
    width: 780px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="mid-section-container">
        <div id="monthly-leaderboard" class="apps-container">
            <div id="monthly-leaderboard-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <h1>Monthly Leaderboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="monthly-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="monthly-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Rank</li>
                        <li>User</li>
                        <li>Wins</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>content goes here.</p>
                <p>and here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tournament-board" class="apps-container">
            <div id="tournament-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upcoming</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tourn-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="tourn-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Platform</li>
                        <li>Torunament</li>
                        <li>Start Time</li>
                        <li>Teams</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share codepen link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this one it is help full**

```css
 
#mid-section-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
.apps-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 617px;
    background-color: black;
}
#monthly-leaderboard {
    right: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
#tournament-board {
    width: 800px;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
.boards-container-nav {
    background-color: #363636;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #25b6e6;
}
#monthly-leaderboard-header h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#tournament-header {
    width: 100%;
}
.apps-content-container {
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#monthly-content {
    width: 286px;
}
#tourn-content {
    width: 780px;
}

ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
}
ul li a{
 color: #FFF;
}
ul li {
 color: #FFF;
}
#tournament-header ul li a{
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
#tourn-content-header ul li{
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
#monthly-content-header ul li{
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
#monthly-content-header{
 background-color: #404040;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
#tourn-content-header{
 background-color: #404040;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mid-section-container">
        <div id="monthly-leaderboard" class="apps-container">
            <div id="monthly-leaderboard-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <h1>Monthly Leaderboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="monthly-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="monthly-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Rank</li>
                        <li>User</li>
                        <li>Wins</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>content goes here.</p>
                <p>and here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="tournament-board" class="apps-container">
            <div id="tournament-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upcoming</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tourn-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="tourn-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Platform</li>
                        <li>Torunament</li>
                        <li>Start Time</li>
                        <li>Teams</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Haha I appreciate the additional efforts of trying to make it look the same! This is definitely the closest I've gotten to fixing it. If you run that code though there still seems to be margin at the top of the ul tag on the #tournament-header. I fixed that with margin 0. Though, in body tag I set all margin to 0 and padding to 0; does it reset an element and all of its children when you make that parent element absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Please update following css into your existing css. just add max-width: 1250px; you want. and margin: 0 auto;

```
#mid-section-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately this did not work it had more to do with removing margins from h1 and ul in both blocks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a unnecessary use of `position:absolute;` i have made changes in your code and removed unwanted css.

```css
#mid-section-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
 display:flex;
}
.apps-container {
    height: 617px;
    background-color: black;
}


.boards-container-nav {
    background-color: #363636;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #25b6e6;
}
#monthly-leaderboard-header {
    height: 85px;
}
#tournament-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
}
.apps-content-container {
    height: 80%;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#tournament-board {
    width: 70%;
}
#monthly-leaderboard {
    width: 30%;
 margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="mid-section-container">
        <div id="tournament-board" class="apps-container">
            <div id="tournament-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Current</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Upcoming</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="tourn-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="tourn-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Platform</li>
                        <li>Torunament</li>
                        <li>Start Time</li>
                        <li>Teams</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div id="monthly-leaderboard" class="apps-container">
            <div id="monthly-leaderboard-header" class="boards-container-nav">
                <h1>Monthly Leaderboard</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="monthly-content" class="apps-content-container">
                <div id="monthly-content-header" class="boards-content-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Rank</li>
                        <li>User</li>
                        <li>Wins</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>content goes here.</p>
                <p>and here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I tried this but still have problems where the top of the containers are separated. Do you mind explaining what 'flex' does with the element also being 'absolute' ?

Comment: A flex container expands items to fill available free space, or shrinks them to prevent overflow. read more: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

add css

```
#mid-section-container{
    display:flex;
}
#monthly-leaderboard{
    width:70%;
    height:100%;
}
#tournament-board{
    width:30%;
    height:100%;
}
```

also add relevant properties of **flex**
may be this is the best way to position divs

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me. Thank you for responding though! Do you mind explaining what 'flex' does to an element that is already 'position: absolute' ?